# Where is get_authorization_header in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use get_authorization_header function which [django-rest-framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework) has but I have this error:

```
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
global name 'get_authorization_header' is not defined
```

So I started to find where is placed this function and I found it [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py) and then imported the module:

```
from rest_framework import authentication
```

The error is still stopping me to continue working. What can be my problem?

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Comment: I did this and solved my problem

`from rest_framework.authentication import get_authorization_header`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method you want is [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/a87c55a93a7ca380bc49425cc6df00f4eba99aa2/rest_framework/authentication.py)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is this:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import get_authorization_header
```